# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'fn' (T_STRING), expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) on laminas-diactoros dependency class on Laravel

Tags: laravel, php-7.4, laminas

Recenty I was updating some code on my Laravel app and I managed to get it working perfectly on local, no error messages whatsoever, so I decided to upload it to the test server.

When I did, this laminas-diactoros package started giving this error message:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'fn' (T_STRING), expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in /route/to/MyProject/vendor/laminas/laminas-diactoros/src/functions/marshal_headers_from_sapi.php on line 29

After some research I learned that this is because in php7.4 fn is a reserved word, so I then did `composer require laminas/laminas-diactoros` to see if updating the package would make it change syntax and work allright. It wont update further than 2.17 and in that version it still uses fn. I don't know what else to see or to do. I'm using laravel 6.20.44, php 7.4 and apache2. If you need any more information just ask and I'll try to answer quick, but this is literally everything I can think of that could be failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Froschdesign in this [post](https://discourse.laminas.dev/t/php-parse-error-on-laminas-diactoros/3466/4) on [Disclosure Laminas](https://discourse.laminas.dev). The problem you're facing is with PHP version conflict between cli and apache2. Your command line shows PHP version 7.4 but confirm in your CPanel and in the Apache virtual host file which version is being used by Apache. Thanks!

```
<?php
// below information gives you the version being used by Apache.
phpinfo();
// below command tells you the version of PHP in the command line.
```

```
$ php --version
```